# How to add regex rules in .ctags file for matching javascript es6 method?

Tags: javascript, regex, ctags

I am using this line for matching methods of javascript file:

`--regex-javascript=/^[ \t]*([A-Za-z0-9_$]+)\(.*\)[ \t]*{/\1/M,Method,Methods/`

But this rule will also match `if()`, `switch()` and `for()`, I changed the rule to 
`--regex-javascript=/^[ \t]*(?!(?:if|for|switch))([A-Za-z0-9_$]+)\(.*\)[ \t]*{/\1/M,Method,Methods/`

But it is not working now, it cannot match any method.

How can I modify the regex then?

The code of rules for matching "methods" in the `.ctags` file is:

```
--regex-javascript=/^[ \t]*this\.([A-Za-z0-9_$]+)[ \t]*=.*{$/\1/M,Method,Methods/
--regex-javascript=/^[ \t]*([A-Za-z0-9_$]+)[ \t]*[:=][ \t]*[\(]*function[ \t]*\(/\1/M,Method,Methods/
--regex-javascript=/^[ \t]*static[ \t]+([A-Za-z0-9_$]+)[ \t]*\(/\1/M,Method,Methods/
--regex-javascript=/^[ \t]*(?!(?:if|for|switch))([A-Za-z0-9_$]+)\(.*\)[ \t]*{/\1/M,Method,Methods/
--regex-javascript=/^[ \t]*([A-Za-z0-9_$]+)\(.*\)[ \t]*{/\1/M,Method,Methods/
```

Comment: Could you give us an example for such a .ctags-File?

Comment: @csabinho I modified the question and added a screenshot.

Comment: I won't ever understand why people take screenshots of text instead of copying it!

Comment: @csabinho sorry, I pasted the code there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Universal Ctags](https://ctags.io/), you can choose an alternative approach.
Universal Ctags provides `{exclusive}` flag. With the flag, you can reject a line matched to a pattern. This feature may help you.

```
$ cat -n /tmp/input.js 
     1  f0 (A) {}
     2  for(something) {}
     3  f1(a) {}
     4  if(1) {}
     5  f2(b) {}
     6  switch(1) {}
     7  f3(c) {}
$ cat -n /tmp/foo.ctags
     1  --regex-javascript=/^[ \t]*this\.([A-Za-z0-9_$]+)[ \t]*=.*\{$/\1/Q,Method,Methods/
     2  --regex-javascript=/^[ \t]*([A-Za-z0-9_$]+)[ \t]*[:=][ \t]*[\(]*function[ \t]*\(/\1/Q,Method,Methods/
     3  --regex-javascript=/^[ \t]*static[ \t]+([A-Za-z0-9_$]+)[ \t]*\(/\1/Q,Method,Methods/
     4  --regex-javascript=/^[ \t]*(if|for|switch)\(.*\)[ \t]*\{//{exclusive}
     5  --regex-javascript=/^[ \t]*([A-Za-z0-9_$]+)\(.*\)[ \t]*\{/\1/Q,Method,Methods/
$ ~/bin/ctags -o - --kinds-javascript=M --options=/tmp/foo.ctags /tmp/input.js 
f1  /tmp/input.js   /^f1(a) {}$/;"  Q
f2  /tmp/input.js   /^f2(b) {}$/;"  Q
f3  /tmp/input.js   /^f3(c) {}$/;"  Q
```